# Mustache with condition display HTML attributes?

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to display HTML attributes in Vue mustache?

```
{{ (data.status)? "<div>Active</div>" : "<div>InActive</div>"}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add HTML within a mustache expression. It causes the expression to not be evaluated.

https://jsfiddle.net/0zaknb56/

What you can do is use the [`v-html`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) directive

```html
<div v-html="data.status ? `<div>Active</div>` : `<div>Inactive</div>`">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7h6osyt9/

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) directive in your case.

```
<div v-if="data.status">Active</div>
<div v-else>Inctive</div>
```