# Split value inside {{ }} to multiple lines (of source code) in Vue

Tags: vue.js

Can I split the value inside `{{ }}` to multiple lines of source code?

```html
<Button
  @click="finishAccountEditing"
/> {{ isCurrentlyEditableAccountIsNew ? StaticStrings.buttons.submitNewAccount.lettering : StaticStrings.buttons.submitEditedAccount.lettering }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can span a mustache expression over any number of lines, provided it's a valid JS expression (and [without HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63822043/283366))

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    isCurrentlyEditableAccountIsNew: true,
    StaticStrings: {buttons:{submitNewAccount:{lettering:"Submit New Account"},submitEditedAccount:{lettering:"Submit Edited Account"}}}
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<button @click="isCurrentlyEditableAccountIsNew = !isCurrentlyEditableAccountIsNew">
  Toggle
</button>
<p>
  {{
    isCurrentlyEditableAccountIsNew 
      ? StaticStrings.buttons.submitNewAccount.lettering 
      : StaticStrings.buttons.submitEditedAccount.lettering 
  }}
</p>
</div>
```

---

If your goal is brevity, nothing beats a computed property

```js
computed: {
  buttonKey: vm => isCurrentlyEditableAccountIsNew
    ? "submitNewAccount" : "submitEditedAccount",
  buttonText: vm => vm.StaticStrings.buttons[vm.buttonKey].lettering
}
```